# Rewrite directory to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a page with two subdomains: [cw.sidenote.hu](http://cw.sidenote.hu) and [cellwars.sidenote.hu](http://cellwars.sidenote.hu), both point to [sidenote.hu/cellwars/](http://sidenote.hu/cellwars/).

What I'd like to achieve that when I visit `cw.sidenote.hu` or `cellwars.sidenote.hu` that the URL change to/stay in `cellwars.sidenote.hu` format, and don't change to `sidenote.hu/cellwars/`.

This is what I currently have in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Some hosts require a rewritebase rule, if so, uncomment the RewriteBase line below. If you are running from a subdirectory, your rewritebase should match the name of the path to where stacey is stored.
# ie. if in a folder named 'stacey', RewriteBase /stacey
#RewriteBase /cellwars

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# Rewrite any calls to *.html, *.json, *.xml, *.atom, *.rss, *.rdf or *.txt if a folder matching * exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1.$2 !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss|rdf|txt)$ $1/ [L]

# Add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ $1/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /* or /app to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /app/$
RewriteRule ^app/ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?$1 [L]

# Rewrite any file calls to the public directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L]
```

These are the rewrite rules I'v tried to use, but it seems this gets the site into an infinite rewrite loop:

```
# cw.sidenote.hu -> cellwars.sidenote.hu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cw.sidenote.hu$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cellwars.sidenote.hu/ [R=301,L]

# sidenote.hu/cellwars/* -> cellwars.sidenote.hu/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cellwars/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cellwars.sidenote.hu/%1 [R=301,L]
```

This is what I got back from Chrome:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://cellwars.sidenote.hu/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
    Reload this webpage later.
    Learn more about this problem.
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your htaccess file content with this (I didn't change anything beyond the `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` line) :

```
RewriteEngine on

# Some hosts require a rewritebase rule, if so, uncomment the RewriteBase line below. If you are running from a subdirectory, your rewritebase should match the name of the path to where stacey is stored.
# ie. if in a folder named 'stacey', RewriteBase /stacey
RewriteBase /

# cw.sidenote.hu -> cellwars.sidenote.hu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cw\.sidenote\.hu$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cellwars.sidenote.hu/$1 [R=301,L]

# sidenote.hu/cellwars/* -> cellwars.sidenote.hu/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sidenote\.hu$
RewriteRule ^cellwars/?(.*)$ http://cellwars.sidenote.hu/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# Rewrite any calls to *.html, *.json, *.xml, *.atom, *.rss, *.rdf or *.txt if a folder matching * exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1.$2 !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss|rdf|txt)$ $1/ [L]

# Add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ $1/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /* or /app to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /app/$
RewriteRule ^app/ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?$1 [L]

# Rewrite any file calls to the public directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. If I entered the subdomain: `cw.sidenote.hu` or `cellwars.sidenote.hu` it changed to `sidenote.hu/cellwars/` and after I couldn't reach any of my pages on the website.